# SQL: multiple select count() displayed on same row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to count a series of variables and then store the results in an array.
This is how I approached it.

```
function statsQuery($array, $column, $table, $columnDate, $minDate, $maxDate) {
    global $query;
    $query = "select ";
    $index = 0;
    $flag = count($array);
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        $index++;
        if ($index == $flag) {
            $query .= "count(case when " . $column . " = '" . $element . "' then " . $column . " else null end) as " . $column . "_" . preg_replace('/\s+/', "_", $element) . " ";
        } else {
            $query .= "count(case when " . $column . " = '" . $element . "' then " . $column . " else null end) as " . $column . "_" . preg_replace('/\s+/', "_", $element) . ", ";
        }
    }
    $query .= " from " . $table;
    $query .= " where " . $columnDate . " between '" . $minDate . "' and '" . $maxDate . "'";
}

statsQuery($genderSection, 'gender', 'candidate', 'candidate_date_introduced', $minDate, $maxDate);
```

Let's say I have this array:

```
$genderSection= array('masculine', 'feminine', 'unspecified');
```

A possible output can be:

```
gender_masculine |  gender_feminine  |  gender_unspecified   | 
--------------------------------------------------------------  
420              | 512               | 23                    |
```

However, the data I need to work with consists of several other variables of this type. For instance:

```
$levelOptions = array('low', 'good', 'acceptable', 'exeptional');
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
gender_masculine |  gender_feminine  |  gender_unspecified   |  level_low |  level_good |  level_acceptable  |  level_exepctional   |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
xx               | xx                | xx                    |  xx        |  xx         |  xx                |  xx                  |
```

I am stuck at the SQL part. I cannot figure out how to make the SQL return the results on the same row. Best option I came up with is running individual queries for each variable using the script above. I tried UNION, JOIN, but no luck.

My questions are:

- how can I query the same table or different tables and get the `count(case)` as a single row? I thought that if I can store everything in an array it will be easier to manipulate and output the data using `foreach`.
- is it performance efficient to get everything as a single row, or should I stick to my current approach and use that function for each variable independently?

Sorry if my questions are silly, I really tried everything I could find around this topic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Added the table structure. The data is introduced via HTML `<select></select>`.

```
id  |  gender       |  level        |
-------------------------------------
1   |  feminine     |  low          |
2   |  mascline     |  good         |
3   |  unspecified  |  acceptable   |
4   |  feminine     |  exceptional  |
.....................................
n   |  feminine     |  exceptional  |
```

Comment: post your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your query with this format

```
SELECT 
count(*) AS total,
SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'masculine' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gender_masculine,
SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'feminine' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gender_feminine,
SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'unspecified' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gender_unspecified,
SUM(CASE WHEN level = 'low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS level_low,
SUM(CASE WHEN level = 'good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS level_good,
SUM(CASE WHEN level = 'acceptable' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS level_acceptable,
SUM(CASE WHEN level = 'exceptional' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS level_exceptional
from table
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected! Using your approach I will have around 50 rows. Is it efficient to have such long queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below :

```
SELECT SUM( IF( gender =  'masculine', 1, 0 ) ) AS gender_masculine, SUM( IF( gender =  'feminine', 1, 0 ) ) AS gender_feminine, SUM( IF( gender =  'unspecified', 1, 0 ) ) AS gender_unspecified, SUM( IF( nlevel =  'low', 1, 0 ) ) AS level_low, SUM( IF( nlevel =  'good', 1, 0 ) ) AS level_good, SUM( IF( nlevel =  'acceptable', 1, 0 ) ) AS level_acceptable, SUM( IF( nlevel =  'exceptional', 1, 0 ) ) AS level_exceptional FROM a_temp
```

Second Approach:
You can also try :

```
SELECT  `nlevel` AS tags, COUNT(  `nlevel` ) AS totals FROM a_temp GROUP BY  `nlevel` UNION ALL SELECT gender AS tags, COUNT( gender ) AS totals FROM a_temp GROUP BY  `gender`
```

Comment: Thank you! I really like your second approach, very neat. However, it only returns a total when there is something to be counted. Can I make it display null when there are no values to count?